# Excel apend tables with duplicate entries of common column

Tags: excel, append, powerquery, vlookup, index-match

I want to combine two tables by my ID column. Both tables have duplicated ID values.

Table 1:

```
ID         Reminder_date     Type
119128      05-Jan           Pear
11601368    07-Jan           Apple
119128      05-Jan           Apple
8445018     04-Jan           Pear
11601368    05-Jan           Grape
119128      04-Jan           Pear
11601368    14-Jan           Grape
5688401     14-Jan           Grape
119128      11-Jan           Pear
11601368    21-Jan           Pear
11045680    11-Jan           Orange
```

Table 2:

```
ID           Purchase_date
11601368     12-Jan
11601368     13-Jan
11601368     11-Jan
119128       11-Jan
119128       29-Jan
8445018      24-Jan
8445018      11-Jan
5688401      28-Jan
11045680     10-Jan
```

I can't use Index match using two columns as they don't have two common columns and I want more rows in my final table.

Ultimately I would want:

```
ID         Reminder_date     Type   Purchase_date
119128      05-Jan           Pear         11-Jan
119128      05-Jan           Pear         29-Jan
11601368    07-Jan           Apple        12-Jan
11601368    07-Jan           Apple        13-Jan
11601368    07-Jan           Apple        11-Jan
119128      05-Jan           Apple        11-Jan
119128      05-Jan           Apple        29-Jan
8445018     04-Jan           Pear         24-Jan
8445018     04-Jan           Pear         11-Jan
11601368    05-Jan           Grape        12-Jan
11601368    05-Jan           Grape        13-Jan
11601368    05-Jan           Grape        11-Jan
119128      04-Jan           Pear         11-Jan
119128      04-Jan           Pear         29-Jan
11601368    14-Jan           Grape        11-Jan
11601368    14-Jan           Grape        13-Jan
11601368    14-Jan           Grape        12-Jan
5688401     14-Jan           Grape        28-Jan
119128      11-Jan           Pear         11-Jan
119128      11-Jan           Pear         29-Jan
11601368    21-Jan           Pear         12-Jan
11601368    21-Jan           Pear         13-Jan
11601368    21-Jan           Pear         11-Jan
11045680    11-Jan           Orange       10-Jan
```

12 entries for 11601368, 8 entries for 119128, 2 entries for 8445018, 1 entry for 5688401, and 1 entry for 11045680

Comment: match 2 items, or even 3, - no splitting needed

Comment: @RolandasKol Just checked, this won't work. I've edited the question to reflect this, thank you though

Comment: It should work, but anyway, your question now is a bit different.
The answer to the current one will depend which method you want to use to solve it...
Power Query, VBA, o simply new table with Formulas linked to other 2 tables?

Comment: @RolandasKol Oh, how would I use Index match in this case, I may be missing something? I thought using index match for multiple columns would mean you needed more than one column in common?
Happy to use any method that gives me a table I can manipulate at the end

Comment: as I understand your amount of data will grow, or most likely is large (and you used just few IDs as example), - I would not go Table with Formulas way (index/match) way as it may become very slow.... Power Query is probably the best "future-proof" solution.
if you can link your example file, - I can make both solutions for you

Comment: That would be fantastic, If I send you an extract could you show me how to do it with power query? @RolandasKol

Comment: I am also still learning, - but will do my best.
P.S. also add the sheet with example with the result needed.

Comment: I have the file ready, but how do I send it to you/ attach it to the question? @RolandasKol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242074/discussion-between-gracetrif-and-rolandas-kol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***M Code***

```
let

//Be sure to change table name in Source lines to actual name in your workbook

//Read in Table 1 and set data types
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tbl_1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Reminder_date", type date}, {"Type", type text}}),

//Add Index column to retain sort order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Read in Table 2 and set data types
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tbl_2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Purchase_date", type date}}),

//Join the tables with a FullOuter join
    joined = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index","ID",#"Changed Type1","ID","Joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),

//resort to original order
//then delete index column
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(joined,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),

//expand the Purchase date column 
    #"Expanded Joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Joined", {"Purchase_date"}, {"Purchase_date"})
in
    #"Expanded Joined"
```

***Tbl_1 & Tbl_2***
[image]

***Results***
[image]